# Enabling a button in jsViews template

Tags: jquery, jsrender, jsviews

I want to enable a button in a jsViews/JsRender template that retrieves employee comments from a database.  That part works fine.  But I need a button that says 'Reply' so others can add their comments to a post.  When that button is clicked, a modal should appear allowing them to enter text.

The button does appear as it should but I cannot get it to perform an action (like fire an alert box, much less a modal).  The demos on the jsViews/jsRender websites work in my server environment, so I know its not a browser or CDN issue.

My first attempt was just to enable the button through jQuery:

```
<script id="theTmpl2" type="text/x-jsrender">

<div class="row">
<div class="card">



<li class="list-group-item">
 <div class="card-block">
  <h6 class="card-title"><b>{{:first_name}} {{:last_name}} 
    {{:id}} 
 </b></h6>

<p class="card-text text-muted large">


<b>Employee ID:</b> {{:emp_id}}<br>
<b>Employee:</b> {{:emp_first}} {{:emp_last}} <br>
<b>Subject:</b> {{:subject}} <br>
<b>Message:</b> {{:message}} <br>
<b>Post Type:</b> {{:post_type}} <br>
<b>Time:</b> {{:timestamp}} <br>

</p>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" 
  id="reply_btn">Reply</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" 
 id="new_post_btn">New Post</button>


</li>

 </div>
 </div>
</div>

</script>




 <script id="theTmpl2" type="text/x-jsrender">

<div class="row">
<div class="card">



 <li class="list-group-item">
 <div class="card-block">
 <h6 class="card-title"><b>{{:first_name}} {{:last_name}} {{:id}} 
 </b></h6>

 <p class="card-text text-muted large">


<b>Employee ID:</b> {{:emp_id}}<br>
<b>Employee:</b> {{:emp_first}} {{:emp_last}} <br>
<b>Subject:</b> {{:subject}} <br>
<b>Message:</b> {{:message}} <br>
<b>Post Type:</b> {{:post_type}} <br>
<b>Time:</b> {{:timestamp}} <br>

</p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" 
  id="reply_btn">Reply</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" 
  id="new_post_btn">New Post</button>


 </li>

   </div>
 </div>
```

```
  <script>
     $( "#new_post_btn" ).click(function() {
     alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
    });
   </script>
```

I then tried (from the demo on the website):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" 
  id="reply_btn">Reply</button>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" 
  id="new_post_btn">New Post</button>

 <span id="topLinked">
  <button data-link="{on ~doSomething}">top level</button>
 </span>

 <script id="tmpl" type="text/x-jsrender">
  <button data-link="{on ~doSomething}">in template</button>
```

With this script:

```
<script>
 var person = {};

 var helpers = {
 doSomething: function() {
  alert("do something");
  }
 }

 $.link(true, "#topLinked", person, helpers); // Data-link top- 
   level content


 </script>
```

In my first attempt, with the jQuery approach, the button does appear on screen, but when I click it nothing happens.

In my second attempt, again two buttons appear ('doSomething') but when I click on them - nothing.

I also tried several other approaches described in the demos on the jsViews/jsRender site but those too were unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have not made a script error that is simply preventing your script from running.

This works for me:

```
<body>
 <span id="topLinked">
  <button data-link="{on ~doSomething}">top level</button>
 </span>
<script>
 var person = {};

 var helpers = {
 doSomething: function() {
  alert("do something");
  }
 }

 $.link(true, "#topLinked", person, helpers); // Data-link top-level content
</script>

</body>
```

But having a newline here - as in your copy above

```
 $.link(true, "#topLinked", person, helpers); // Data-link top-(You put a new-line here!) 
   level content
```

will be invalid javascript. Did you put a breakpoint in your script and run in a debugger?

For your other samples you have not included the code where you render and link the template...

Anyway, for any sample such as https://www.jsviews.com/#link-events@button, you can simply copy exactly the contents of the ***Full Code*** tab, then it should work exactly as in the demo (such as the code below). Then you can iteratively change to your own version.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.jsviews.com/download/jsviews.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://www.jsviews.com/samples/samples.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

<style>
  .red {color: red!important;}
</style>

<span id="result"></span>

<script id="tmpl" type="text/x-jsrender">
  <button data-link="{on ~doSomething}" id="btn0">Click me</button>

  {^{on ~doSomething}}<button id="btn1">Click me</button>{{/on}}

  {^{on ~doSomething}}Click me{{/on}}

  {^{on ~doSomething tmpl="Click me" /}}

  {^{on ~doSomething /}}

  {^{on ~doSomething height=18 width=75 class="red" id="btn5"}}Click me{{/on}}
</script>

<script>
var tmpl = $.templates("#tmpl");

var person = {};

var helpers = {
  doSomething: function(ev) {
    alert("do something. id: " + ev.target.id);
  }
}

tmpl.link("#result", person, helpers); // Render and link the template

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi thanks Boris - I think the newline thing is just a bad copy/paste job on my part. I can absolutely recreate all the demos on the site, and have tried to do exactly what you suggest -  add my content piece by piece.  Still no luck. My template is called "theTmpl2" but when I change var tmpl = $.templates("#tmpl"); to var tmpl = $.templates("#theTmpl2"); I get an error that {{:first_name}} is invalid  - is that an incorrect approach?

Comment: I can't help more at this point. I leave on a trip tomorrow. But it sounds anyway like you need to just debug your code further. (Of course $.templates("#theTmpl2") is valid syntax, but I don't know whether the content of your template is valid, and can't look further now...).

Comment: No worries Boris, thanks for your help.  I like your code very much and look forward to using it.  Safe travels and I will ping you later if necessary.